# problem with using csv format files in python

Tags: python, csv

I was doing a project in python using csv files with csv library and also statistics mean function and I faced an issue with the output. Not sure why it was happened.Here is my code:

```
def calculate_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    fileName = input_file_name
    grades = []
    average = OrderedDict()
    with open(fileName, newline ='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        try:
            for lines in reader:
                name = lines[0]
                for row in lines[1:]:
                    grades.append(int(row))
                grades_mean = mean(grades)
                average[name] = grades_mean
                #print(lines)
        except csv.Error as e:
            exit(f"file name {fileName}, line {reader.line_num} : {e}")
        with open(output_file_name, 'w', newline='') as output:
            writer = csv.writer(output)
            for key, values in average.items():
                writer.writerow([key, values])
```

I was trying to read a csv file from my localhost and then split the names and grades one another and try to put the floats into the list and take the mean of each line which is the grades by each person and put the names and the means together in an ordered dict. The method is actually working but not giving accurate means.

Comment: You're not emptying `grades` between each line. So you're appending each student's grades to the grades of all the students before them.

Comment: Move `grades = []` inside the loop.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. These techniques will help you find where in your code the problem occurs.

Comment: BTW, `row` is a poor variable name. You're iterating over fields of the line, not rows of the file.

Comment: If you'd put `print(grades)` instead of `print(lines)` you would surely have noticed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the fact that `grades` is outside of the for loop, thus it accumulates the grades for all names. You need to move it inside the `for ... in reader` loop. Better yet, we can use list comprehension. Here is one way to solve this:

```py
import csv
from statistics import mean


def calculate_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    average = []
    with open(input_file_name) as stream:
        reader = csv.reader(stream)
        for row in reader:
            name = row[0]
            grades = [float(value) for value in row[1:]]
            grades_mean = mean(grades)
            average.append((name, f"{grades_mean:>0.1f}"))

    with open(output_file_name, "w") as stream:
        writer = csv.writer(stream)
        writer.writerows(average)
```

Notes

- I rename `lines` to `row`: `lines` is misleading because it represent just a line of text
- I also rename `row` to `value`: Again, row is misleading because it represent a number, which is part of a row
- I removed the try/except construct: If there is an error, the output will be more helpful than just printing out an error message
- I removed the use of `OrderedDict` because a simple tuple is enough. My assumption is names are not repeated.
- I formatted the grade to `0.1f` specification, making the output neater
- I un-indent the `with open(output ...` to make the code less deeply nested
- I replaced `.writerow` with `.writerows`